# Application compiled with Delphi 2010 (Windows XP3 machine) don't run on Windows 7 - error at kernelbase.dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Application compiled with Delphi 2010 (Windows XP3 machine) don't run on Windows 7. However, it runs fine on Windows XP. I see no special message when the program is compiled with D2010. Third party component used are AnyDAC and wwDBGrid (woo2wool).

Here the event message produced when executed on W7 (the program just don't start, windows shows a message saying that something is wrong with the executable) Error in the event is shown at KERNELBASE.DLL level:

```
Nom du journal :Application
Source :       Application Error
Date :         2010-10-05 15:35:43
ID de l’événement :1000
Catégorie de la tâche :(100)
Niveau :       Erreur
Mots clés :    Classique
Utilisateur :  N/A
Ordinateur :   Toshiba
Description :
Nom de l’application défaillante AccWrks100708.exe, version : 1.0.0.708,
horodatage : 0x4cab70cf
Nom du module défaillant : KERNELBASE.dll, version : 6.1.7600.16385,
horodatage : 0x4a5bdbdf
Code d’exception : 0x0eedfade
Décalage d’erreur : 0x0000b727
ID du processus défaillant : 0x1b38
Heure de début de l’application défaillante : 0x01cb64c47f2b62b4
Chemin d’accès de l’application défaillante :
D:\Projets\AccWork\Data\AcctWrks100708.exe
Chemin d’accès du module défaillant: C:\windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
ID de rapport : bdef3db4-d0b7-11df-b4a4-f5366bb499ed
XML de l’événement :
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-10-05T19:35:43.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>15500</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Toshiba</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>AcctWrks100708.exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.708</Data>
    <Data>4cab70cf</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.1.7600.16385</Data>
    <Data>4a5bdbdf</Data>
    <Data>0eedfade</Data>
    <Data>0000b727</Data>
    <Data>1b38</Data>
    <Data>01cb64c47f2b62b4</Data>
    <Data>D:\Projets\AccountWork\Data\AcctWrks100708.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>bdef3db4-d0b7-11df-b4a4-f5366bb499ed</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

---

I have no idea what is going wrong (i personnaly do not have W7). 
Help appreciated. Tx.

===============

UPDATE:

RESOLVED: It was a third party component - not compatible with W7.

Comment: Maybe you could answer your own question and put the name of the third party component.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem - what was the 3rd party component?

Comment: look above. "Third party component used are AnyDAC and wwDBGrid (woo2wool). "

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because an exception was being hidden because of the Locale of the new machine was set to use "," as a decimal seperator instead of a ".".

The error (after debugging) was saying that `"2.2 is not a valid floating point"` - and this was only happening in Windows 10 - because the locale changed it's default in Windows 10, it was always "." for South Africa, but then changed to ",".

Check the Region -> Formats -> Additional Settings -> Decimal Symbol value